# move-only input and output iterators

Tags: c++, c++11, iterator, move

Concerning [InputIterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/InputIterator)/[OutputIterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/OutputIterator)-s is it consistent to modify their semantics to be move-only? Surely I mean only newly-created custom iterators, not *STL* ones.

Notes to semantic requirements to `++i` and `++r` expressions for input and output iterators correspondingly says:

> Postcondition: Any copies of the previous value of `i` are no longer required to be either dereferenceable or to be in the domain of `==`.
>
> After this operation `r` is not required to be incrementable and any copies of the previous value of `r` are no longer required to be dereferenceable or incrementable.

I think it is safer to prohibit possibility to have a copies of input/output iterators in most cases, but never heard such advice. Is it bad idea?

Comment: If I had a time machine, making these iterators move-only in C++98 would be near the top of my list.  Making your custom input/output iterators move-only is a safe experiment.  If you try to use them with code that does try to copy them, you will be alerted at compile-time, and you can then inspect that situation.  It might even point out a bug in that generic code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Input/OutputIterators must first satisfy the Iterator requirement. And that requirement say, from C++14, [iterator.iterators], p2:

> A type `X` satisfies the `Iterator` requirements if:
>
> - `X` satisfies the `CopyConstructible`, `CopyAssignable`, and `Destructible` requirements (17.6.3.1)

So no, they cannot be move-only.

Comment: Now I understand this, but I feel, that they should be move-only initially (as `std::istream` is for example). Howard Hinnant confirms my considerations.

Comment: @Orient: Whether I agree or not, your question was "can it be done"? The answer is "not according to the standard". The Ranges TS similarly requires that they are copyable.

Answer (score 5):

In C++20, the new iterators concepts `input_iterator` and `output_iterator` do not require to be copyable.
The algorithms in the `ranges` namespace, as well as the view adapters support move only iterators too.

The new view `ranges::istream_view` returns move-only iterator for increased safety.
Finally the new C++20 `view` concept does itself not require copyability which allows its own state to be move only.

It is still possible to create `copyable` `input_iterator` and `output_iterator` that are not `copyable` but I would advise not to.

`forward_iterator`s are, of course, still required to be `copyable`. Sentinels also require to be `copyable`

You can read ore about the design in the following papers

- [Movability of Single-pass Iterators](https://wg21.link/p1207)
- [Move-only views](https://wg21.link/p1456)
- [Ranges adaptors for non-copyable iterators](https://wg21.link/p1862)

Answer (score -1):

That is probably not a good idea.  Iterator objects are usually designed to be lightweight and are passed around by value in order to be efficient.  And many of the C++ standard library containers use iterators passed by value. Disabling the copy constructors does not seem like a good idea at all to me.

For example see http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/vector/ the vector constructor accepts the input iterator by value.

And see http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/copy/ for an example of a C++ standard library container that accepts an output iterator by value

Comment: It is not the problem at all: I can pass iterator value using `std::move`.

Comment: That would be passing an iterator rvalue reference.  Why would you want to do that?

Comment: And that would still have overhead associated with it.  Why move an iterator to another location when it is more efficient and takes less assembly code to copy?

Comment: I want to prohibit a copies of input/output iterator.

Comment: Why do you think `std::move` introduce any additional overhead? It is just semantic action.

Comment: That is not a good idea.  Lots of algorithms need to make copies.  See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/merge/ , I can imagine lots of systems have libraries that make copies of iterators

Comment: Not really, it would involve moving an iterator to a new location and invalidating the old one.  That would be a proper move.  And move semantics with respect to pointers (and correspondingly iterators) does not seem to make any sense.

Comment: `std::merge` algorithm not requires any copy of iterators - I see it clearly.

Comment: If you only had move constructors enabled.  How could the result iterator be used twice if it was already moved with a call to `std::copy`?

Comment: It make sense (see the question). Even if iterator still remains trivially move-constructible/assignable.

Comment: Move semantics were not introduced for this purpose.  That is like saying you should move an integer to another location rather than copy it because it wont be used again in the future in the context of the original copy

Comment: `std::copy` is just one coditional branch. They'll be moved to parameters of either `std::copy` iff either corresponding condition holds.

Comment: Can't agree. I think there might be a broader view of the problem.

Comment: Also look at this http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/all_of/ If the iterator was move only it could never be incremented after it was passed into the predicate as an rvalue

Comment: __Total misunderstanding.__ Sorry, let's stop the discussion

Comment: See counterexample to your thoughts http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2039b077e92a8983 .