# How do move-only iterator implement postfix ++ operator?

Tags: c++, c++20

What is the right way to implement an iterator that iterates over a Recordset provided below in C++ style?

```
class Recordset
{
public:

    Recordset(const Recordset&) = delete;

    Recordset& operator = (const Recordset&) = delete;

    Recordset(Recordset&& other) noexcept = default;

    Recordset& operator = (Recordset&&) = default;

    //Moves to the next record. Returns false if the end is reached.
    bool Next();

    //Gets the current record as an instance of type T.
    template <class T>
    void Get(T& val);
};
```

my idea is that I probably do something like this:

```
template <class T>
class Iterator
{
public:

    using iterator_category = std::forward_iterator_tag;

    using value_type = T;

    using difference_type = std::ptrdiff_t;

    using pointer = value_type*;

    using reference = value_type&;

    Iterator() = default;
    
    Iterator(Recordset s) : m_i(std::move(s))
    {
        try_next();
    }

    Iterator(const Iterator&) = delete;

    Iterator& operator = (const Iterator&) = delete;

    Iterator(Iterator&& other) = default;

    Iterator& operator = (Iterator&& other) = default;

    T* operator-> () { return cur(); }

    T* operator* () { return cur(); }

    bool operator== (const Iterator& other) const noexcept
    {
        //They both are end().
        return !m_v && !other.m_v;
    }

    bool operator!= (const Iterator& other) const noexcept
    {
        return !operator==(other);
    }

    Iterator& operator++ ()
    {
        this->try_next();

        return *this;
    }

    Iterator operator++ (int)
    {
        Iterator tmp = *this; //would not compile.

        this->try_next();

        return tmp;
    }

private:

    bool try_next()
    {
        if (m_i.Next())
        {
            T val;
            m_i.Get(val);

            m_v = val;

            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    T* cur()
    {
        T& val = *m_v;

        return &val;
    }

    Recordset m_i;

    std::optional<T> m_v;
};

template <class T>
std::ranges::subrange<Iterator<T>> make_range(Recordset& s)
{
    return std::ranges::subrange(Iterator<T>(s), Iterator<T>{});
}
```

and use it as follows:

```
struct Record { int x; std::string y; };

int main()
{
    Recordset s;

    for (Record& r : make_range(s))
    {
        std::cout << r.x << r.y << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The frist question is how do I implement `Iterator operator++ (int)` if both `Recordset` and `Iterator` are [move-only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35243358/move-only-input-and-output-iterators)? (`temp` and `this` can't point to different records, because there is only one current record in the recordset). Does C++20 require it?

The second question is it a good idea to implement `end()` in this way? (`end()` is a simply an iterator containing an empty `optional`)

Comment: I realize I haven't head about a _move only_ iterator as something you provide from the **container**. If the object can be moved, let it move.

Comment: you probably want to say **Input Iterator** (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/InputIterator)

Comment: @TedLyngmo do you mean `I haven't heard`? I so, the are mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35243358/move-only-input-and-output-iterators

Comment: @appleapple it is not clear how does it relate to new iterators concepts input_iterator and output_iterator in C++20

Comment: @AlexeyStarinsky :-) yes, `"heard"` and `"head`" ...  Ok, I'm not 100% up to speed with C++20 but, as I could read (briefly)  in that question, it's not really "a thing". A proper `move_iterator` isn't a big deal and it's been around for some time, but... well, I may return in a few hours to read more about this. Sounds exciting.

Comment: @TedLyngmo `std::move_iterator` and move-only iterator are different things, I have the second one.

Comment: I know what the  `move_iterator` does.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Single pass move-only input iterators (A c++20 [`std::input_iterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/input_iterator)) are only required to be [weakly incremental](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/weakly_incrementable), where `(void) ++i` has the same effect as `(void) i++`. You can simply have `void operator++(int) { ++*this; }`. Older requirements for iterators ([Cpp17InputIterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/InputIterator)) requires iterators to be copyable, and require `operator++` to return that copy.

And for your second question, you might want to use a sentinel type, something like:

```cpp
template<typename T>
bool operator==(const Iterator<T>& it, std::default_sentinel_t) {
    return !it.m_v;
}

// != can be rewritten from ==, so no need to write one

template <class T>
auto make_range(Recordset& s)
{
    return std::ranges::subrange(Iterator<T>(s), std::default_sentinel);
}
```

And if you need to work with a algorithm that can't use separate sentinel types, use [`ranges::common_view`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/common_view). Your current solution also works, except you need to have `this == &other || (!m_v && !other.m_v);`.

Comment: I believe it requires `*i++` to be valid (and the result is pre-increment item). does it changed?

Comment: @ Artyer, I mean, from the link you post https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/InputIterator it does specify the *semantic* of `*i++` (which does what I said), does it changed after c++17/20?

Comment: @appleapple Oh I was looking at the C++20 one. C++17 iterators had to be copyable so I guess it required `i++` to return a copy. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: @Artyer Thanks! Everything works except `std::ranges::common_view`, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73754698/how-to-create-a-common-range