# How to create a common range?

Tags: c++, c++20

Why doesn't `std::ranges::common_view` compile in the code below?

```
#include <ranges>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

template <class T>
struct IteratorSentinel {};

template <class T>
class Iterator
{
public:

    using iterator_category = std::input_iterator_tag;

    using value_type = T;

    using difference_type = std::ptrdiff_t;

    using pointer = value_type*;

    using reference = value_type&;

    Iterator() = default;

    Iterator(const Iterator&) = delete;

    Iterator& operator = (const Iterator&) = delete;

    Iterator(Iterator&& other) = default;

    Iterator& operator = (Iterator&& other) = default;

    T* operator-> () { return cur(); }

    T& operator* () { return *cur(); }

    T& operator* () const { return *cur(); };

    bool operator== (const IteratorSentinel<T>&) const noexcept;

    Iterator& operator++ ();

    void operator++ (int);

private:

    T* cur() const
    {
        return pCur;
    }

    T* pCur = nullptr;
};

static_assert(std::input_iterator<Iterator<int>>); 

template <class T>
auto make_range()
{
    return std::ranges::subrange(Iterator<T>(), IteratorSentinel<T>{});
}

int main()
{
    auto r = make_range<int>();

    auto cr = std::ranges::common_view{ r };

    std::vector<int> v;

    std::copy(cr.begin(), cr.end(), std::back_inserter(v));

    return 0;
}
```

Can't figure out what template parameter does it require.

MSVC2022 error (/std:c++latest):

```
error C2641: cannot deduce template arguments for 'std::ranges::common_view'
error C2893: Failed to specialize function template 'std::ranges::common_view<_Vw> std::ranges::common_view(_Vw) noexcept(<expr>)'
```

GCC12 errors:

```
prog.cc: In function 'int main()':
prog.cc:67:43: error: class template argument deduction failed:
   67 |     auto cr = std::ranges::common_view{ r };
      |                                           ^
prog.cc:67:43: error: no matching function for call to 'common_view(std::ranges::subrange<Iterator<int>, IteratorSentinel<int>, std::ranges::subrange_kind::unsized>&)'
In file included from prog.cc:1:
/opt/wandbox/gcc-12.1.0/include/c++/12.1.0/ranges:3724:7: note: candidate: 'template<class _Vp> common_view(_Vp)-> std::ranges::common_view<_Vp>'
 3724 |       common_view(_Vp __r)
      |       ^~~~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: Poor question as it does not mention compiler nor compiler error message. For which standard are you compiling (C++ 20, C++23, latest)?

Comment: `common_iterator` requires the underlying iterator to be `copyable`. Since your `Iterator` is a move-only type, which cannot use to construct a `common_iterator`, which makes `ranges::common_view` ill-formed.

Comment: See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/common_view, it contains `std::copyable<ranges::iterator_t<V>>` requirement for input iterator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your range is built out of an iterator/sentinel pair. The definition of a common range is a range where the sentinel type *is an iterator*. So the range itself is not a common range.

[`common_view` can generate a common range from a non-common range](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/common_view). Which means that it will have to create two iterators. And since it starts the process with only one iterator, that means that, at some point, it must *copy* that iterator (thus creating two usable iterators).

Which it can't do because your iterator is non-copyable. Which is why `common_view` has an explicit requirement that the iterator is copyable.

Comment: Great answer but: "the sentinel type is an iterator" shouldn't this read as "the sentinel should be the same type as the iterator"?